# How to program an Inovatic USB interface?

Tags: microcontroller

In my possession I have an [Inovatic USB Interface](http://www.inovatic-ict.com/didactic-equipment/emoro-kits-overview/emoro-usb-classic.html). (In Detail: UI-8x8 v1.1 2009) I would like to program it to do some simple stuff and things. I am familiar with C# Programming but from what i have heard its not possible to program this interface with C#.

What it looks like:

[image: Interface from the top]
[image: The USB port on the Interface]
[image: The USB Cable used to connect the Interface to the computer]

- Where can I find the Drivers for this Interface?  I have checked the Inovatic website but they only have the v1.0 version of the drivers and I'm pretty sure that I need v1.1 !
- How can i program it? What language do i use?

Comment: I'd imagine that contacting Inovatic directly would be the best way to get the answers you are looking for.

Comment: Tried that like 2 months ago and still nothing :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Drivers

The only link they have to download drivers is on [their download page](http://www.inovatic-ict.com/didactic-equipment/download.html). Unfortunately the link to the EMoRo USB drivers returns a 404 error. I have attempted to send a message to the company to let them know.

As for the version of the driver, the only way you'll know if the v1.0 driver will work is if you try it. Since nothing else is available at the moment, you should try working with the driver you have and see if you have any problems relating to that.

### Programming Tools

According to the page you linked in your question:

> The kit is designed for users who wish to program the robot with a flowchart or in the Basic programming language... Advanced users can program the robot in Bascom-AVR or AVR C and they can build their own autonomous robot.

So you can either use their flow-chart programming environment, you can use Bascom-AVR (which is BASIC for AVR microcontrollers), or you can program it in C. It looks like Inovatic's [download page](http://www.inovatic-ict.com/didactic-equipment/download.html) has IDEs and compilers available to download for free to use any of these options.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! About the drivers, i was able to download the drivers (and still have them on my PC) but when i install them they dont work.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? As in, you can't upload code to it? Does windows say something about driver installation failing? What do you see in the device manager when you plug this device into your computer (assuming you're using windows)?

Comment: When i connect it to the compute it detects it but dosent have drivers for it and when windows tries to download drivers it fails because it can't find them. When i installed the v1.0 Drivers form Inovatics website they didn't work either!